# How to draw an edge further away in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-path

In the example below you can see an illustration of the problem I have. I would like to draw an error from node s to 6, but I want to clear node 1. It is easy to do using `\draw` as you can see from the red dotted line. However, I would much rather find the correct option and have it included in the `\path` command. Grateful for any help.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, 
                automata,
                intersections,
                positioning,
                quotes,
                matrix
                }
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,fit}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance = 30mm and 40mm,
        dot/.style = {circle, fill=red, inner sep=2pt, node contents={}},
every state/.style = {circle, draw=red, very thick},
 every edge/.style = {draw=blue, line width=1pt, -Stealth,
                      shorten >=2pt, shorten <=2pt,
                      },
 every edge quotes/.style = {auto, sloped, inner sep=2pt},
       every label/.style = {rectangle, inner sep=2pt, font=\large},
     mincut/.style = {draw=green!40!black, line width=3pt, dashed}
                                              ]

\node[state]  at (0, 0)  (1) [label=left:{ $ $}] {$1$};
\node[state]  (4) [right= of 1, label=right:{ $ $}] {4};
\node[state]  (2) [above=  of 4, label=above:{ $ $}] {2};
\node[state]  (6) [below right=2 and 1.7 of 4, label=below:{ $ $}] {6};

\node[state]  (s) [above=  of 1, label=above:{ $ $}] {s};


\path       (s) edge["{$5,0$}"]                 (1)
                edge["{$1,0$}"]                 (2)
                edge["{$2,0$} ",out=180,in=200] (6)

            (1) edge["{$2,2$}"]                 (2)
                edge["{$3,1$}"]                 (4)
                edge["{$2,2$}"]                 (6);
                
                
\draw[red,->,very thick,dashed] (s) .. controls (-3,-2) .. (6);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Well, you already found Bézier curves. They take more than one control point: ‘.. controls (1,2) and (2,3) .. ‘  and should ultimately be able to do what you want with a little trial and error.

Comment: And in terms of adding that to your single draw command ( which I personally find a bit questionable) you should be able to just add it using the ‘--‘ syntax instead of ‘edge’.

Comment: FYI: I added another option to my answer, which I thought of immediately after posting.

Comment: @MarkusG. , I have been under the impression, from other post that I have read, that it is better to use ```\path``` as opposed to ```\draw``` but I don't know why. Can you explain?

Comment: Well, \draw is just shorthand for \path[draw] so I rarely ever use \path in my tikzpictures.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wouldn't say using an additional `\draw` is any less correct, but you can play with the `looseness` parameter, in addition to the `in` and `out` angles. For example,

```
edge["{$2,0$} ", out=230, in=180, looseness=1.4] (6)
```

Alternatively, specify a custom path with `to path`, e.g.

```
edge["{$2,0$} ", to path={(\tikztostart) .. controls +(-4,-5) and +(-4,-1) ..  (\tikztotarget) \tikztonodes}] (6)
```

See section 14.13 *The To Path operation* in the manual.

Below I also used the `bbox` library to get a better bounding box.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, 
                automata,
                intersections,
                positioning,
                quotes,
                matrix,
                bbox % <-- added
                }
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,fit}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance = 30mm and 40mm,
        dot/.style = {circle, fill=red, inner sep=2pt, node contents={}},
every state/.style = {circle, draw=red, very thick},
 every edge/.style = {draw=blue, line width=1pt, -Stealth,
                      shorten >=2pt, shorten <=2pt,
                      },
 every edge quotes/.style = {auto, sloped, inner sep=2pt},
       every label/.style = {rectangle, inner sep=2pt, font=\large},
     mincut/.style = {draw=green!40!black, line width=3pt, dashed}
                                              ]

\node[state]  at (0, 0)  (1) [label=left:{ $ $}] {$1$};
\node[state]  (4) [right= of 1, label=right:{ $ $}] {4};
\node[state]  (2) [above=  of 4, label=above:{ $ $}] {2};
\node[state]  (6) [below right=2 and 1.7 of 4, label=below:{ $ $}] {6};

\node[state]  (s) [above=  of 1, label=above:{ $ $}] {s};


\path [bezier bounding box] % for improved bounding box calculation, requires bbox library
            (s) edge["{$5,0$}"]                 (1)
                edge["{$1,0$}"]                 (2)
                edge["{$2,0$} ", out=230, in=180, looseness=1.4] (6)
                edge["{$2,0$} ", red, dashed, to path={(\tikztostart) .. controls +(-3,-7) and +(-5,0) ..  (\tikztotarget) \tikztonodes}] (6)

            (1) edge["{$2,2$}"]                 (2)
                edge["{$3,1$}"]                 (4)
                edge["{$2,2$}"]                 (6)
               ;

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That is just what I needed. Thanks for the ```bbox``` tip also.